# Javascript access click drop-down element

Tags: javascript, html, c++, qt, dom

Note: I'm very low in JS and DOM and I work with it through C++ Qt.

I need to click programmatically first drop-down element in Facebook search:
http://pastexen.com/i/0XnZWs4QNx.png
but seems that elements loads dynamically and I can't access them with JS and evaluate click. What can I do? How can I access that element? Help me, I have no more ideas.

P.S. And maybe you know better ways to get Facebook search results with that five options?

```
_browser->load(FB_SIMPLE_SEARCH);
waitUntilTimeOutOrLoaded();
QWebElement elem_doc = _browser->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement();
QWebElement elem_univer = elem_doc.findFirst("input[class=\"inputtext textInput\"]");
elem_univer.setAttribute("value", _ui->lineEditUniver->text());
_dont_stop = true;
waitUntilTimeOutOrLoaded();
elem_univer.setFocus();
_dont_stop = true;
waitUntilTimeOutOrLoaded();
qDebug() << _browser->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("li[class=page]").isNull();
qDebug() << _browser->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("li[class=page]").isNull();
qDebug() << _browser->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("li[class=\"page selected\"]").isNull();
qDebug() << _browser->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("li[class=\"page selected\"]").isNull();
```

All four is NULL.
When in _browser all ok and element is visible:
http://pastexen.com/i/bbb8zgEKZF.png

Comment: What have you tried to achieve what you're trying to do? Gotta show what you've tried to get an answer. We're here to help you debug code, not write it for you.

Comment: I want programmatically execute search. Where did I ask your to write code for me? I asked how I can fill that field with first element of drop-down list, because I can't find way to access that element through JS, because it's load dynamically and there is no such element in source code.

Comment: Yeah, you need to provide code that you have written yourself to show what you've tried to achieve your goal. Again, we're not here to write code for you or to set you on the right path. You have to show what you've attempted to achieve your result, and we can help you debug your code from there.

Comment: I added the code, but as I said I work from C++ Qt.

Comment: In response to your edited comment, by posting a question without code, it generally comes off as the person is asking or people to write code for them to achieve their goal. Further, you're citing an issue with your code, but how can we help you troubleshoot your code if we can't see it? Providing a sample of your code, specifically the part that has the problem, is basically rule number one here, otherwise it makes it look like you've made no effort to achieve your goal and simply want people to do your work for you.

Comment: I understood my mistake and give now full information :)